# How to pass an object to a script?

Tags: c#, roslyn

In the following snippet, how do I pass my object as parameter to the method in the script?

```
var c = new MyAssembly.MyClass()
{
    Description = "test"
};

var code = "using MyAssembly;" +
           "public class TestClass {" +
           "  public bool HelloWorld(MyClass c) {" +
           "    return c == null;" +
           "  }" +
           "}";

var script = CSharpScript.Create(code, options, typeof(MyAssembly.MyClass));
var call = await script.ContinueWith<int>("new TestClass().HelloWorld()", options).RunAsync(c);
```

Comment: Read the document: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Scripting-API-Samples

Comment: But you seems to need a compiler to compile your class rather than a script engine to execute some code. Use `CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText`: http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/compiling-c-sharp-code-into-memory-and-executing-it-with-roslyn

Comment: @Tommy The samples should how to parameterize the script but in my case I want to pass a parameter to the method, which the samples do not show. ParseText seems interesting but I don't want to create temporary assemblies before executing the code.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `Globals` type should hold any global variable declarations as it's properties.

Assuming you got the correct references for your script:

```
var metadata = MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(MyClass).Assembly.Location);
```

---

**Option 1**

You need to define a global var of type MyClass:

```
public class Globals
{
    public MyClass C { get; set; }
}
```

And use that as a `Globals` type:

```
var script = 
    await CSharpScript.Create(
        code: code,
        options: ScriptOptions.Default.WithReferences(metadata),
        globalsType: typeof(Globals))
    .ContinueWith("new TestClass().HelloWorld(C)")
    .RunAsync(new Globals { C = c });

var output = script.ReturnValue;
```

Note that in the `ContinueWith` expression the is a `C` variable as well as a `C` property in `Globals`. That should do the trick.

---

**Option 2**

In your case it might make sense to create a delegate if you intend to call the script multiple times:

```
var f =
    CSharpScript.Create(
        code: code,
        options: ScriptOptions.Default.WithReferences(metadata),
        globalsType: typeof(Globals))
    .ContinueWith("new TestClass().HelloWorld(C)")
    .CreateDelegate();

var output = await f(new Globals { C = c });
```

---

**Option 3**

In your case you don't even need to pass any `Globals`

```
var f =
    await CSharpScript.Create(
        code: code,
        options: ScriptOptions.Default.WithReferences(metadata))
    .ContinueWith<Func<MyClass, bool>>("new TestClass().HelloWorld")
    .CreateDelegate()
    .Invoke();

var output = f(c);
```

Comment: Great answer where all options work as expected. The examples show what is possible with Roslyn and should be included in the samples.