# Pass array as input parameter in CSharpScript

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, roslyn, csharpscript

I try to run method by CSharpScript.

Method:

```
public class TaskSolution 
{ 
   public int[] Calculate(int[] inputValue) 
   {
      return inputValue;
   }
}
```

I tried this solution:

```
var script = CSharpScript.Create(solution.Code);
var input = new int[3] { 1, 2, 3 };
var call = await script.ContinueWith<int[]>($"new TaskSolution().Calculate({input})").RunAsync();
```

But it throws `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.CompilationErrorException` with text `"(1,43): error CS0443: Syntax error; value expected"` and no more information inside.

When I run similar method but with simple input parameter (as int or string) - it runs successfully. But I meet problems with using arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$"new TaskSolution().Calculate({input})"` evaluates to `"new TaskSolution().Calculate(System.Int32[])"`, which is not valid code. `input` would be treated as string, not passed as the actual array.

Comment: Ooh, thank you. Your comment helped me to understand that I should use another way of implementation.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38278701/how-to-pass-an-object-to-a-script - one of these ways